# How to delete a user default value in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I.e., my app sets some standard default values at the beginning. Then those values may get overridden by the user. And when the user messes things up, I want to set those settings back to my app default values. As I understand it, the app defaults are a different dictionary than the user defaults, and the user defaults just override those app defaults. But I haven't seen methods for deleting the user defaults. Any idea?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Try [`removeObjectForKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutabledictionary/1416518-removeobjectforkey) -- that should give you the ability to remove a preference.

Answer (score 103):

Use this code

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"MyKey"];
```

**dont forget to synchronize if you want to save immediately**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

[NSUserDefaults Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**synchronize** - This method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes.

**Swift 5:**

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "MyKey")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Comment: +1 for [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize ]; I usually forget to add this.

Comment: if you wont synchronize, it will automatically synchronize it when you close your app.

Comment: @yucelbayram -> yup, but if you want to save immediately then you have to syn.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 yes that's true.

Comment: Apple documentation currently says about the synchronize method: "Waits for any pending asynchronous updates to the defaults database and returns; this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used." You don't need to use this anymore.

Answer (score 8):

```
NSUserDefaults * removeUD = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[removeUD removeObjectForKey:@"shoping"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize ];
```

Answer (score 8):

Swift version for easy copy pasting:

```
var idForUserDefaults = "somestupidtext"
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.removeObjectForKey(idForUserDefaults)
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

or

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("somestupidtext")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Comment: The Apple documents state that `.synchronize()`  "is unnecessary and shouldn't be used. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize

Answer (score 7):

#### To remove a specific KEY value:

**Swift 3+**

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "KEY")
```

**Obj-C**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"KEY"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

---

#### If you need to **reset UserDefaults/Clear All datas**:

```
NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```

**Swift 3:**

```
if let bundle = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
    UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: bundle)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Updated for Swift 3.0 code:

`UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "YOURKEY")`

Comment: `Value of type 'UserDefaults' has no member 'remove'`

Comment: kbunarjo,  Did you even try this.  LOL.  Swift 3 -UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "Key")

Comment: @Jeff they just recently released a newer version of Swift 3 (3.1). I haven't taken a look at the docs yet, so I'm assuming this is why my version doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Ya,  thought it was funny :)

Comment: UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "YOURKEY");

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4

```
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "your_key")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift way**

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "aKey")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```