# How to save integer value to NSuserDefault like sqlite?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I want to save and retrieve value in NSUserDefault. I am saving and retrieving Value sucessfully. But when I go cak Homepage and again come in my class The value is not stored and all the process done again. It doesnot Remember old value.

I am doing this-

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad{
    A = 0;                // int A; defone in .h
    [self calling_Once];
}

-(void)calling_Once{
     NSLog(@"A is: %d",A);     // A is always zero when I leave this class and return Back to this class. This is my only problem. I want A=1; when I go back And return to this class but 
     NSInteger B = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"save_Interger_Value_For_Formula_One"];  //is not able to remeber value. It gives A=0; B =0; When I come back to this class, I want It should return A=1; B=1; and remember old value like sqlite when I return to this class.

     if (A==0) {
         [self refreshButton];
         NSLog(@"Before Increment A is: %d",A);
         A++;

         NSLog(@"After Increment A is: %d",A);

         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:A forKey:@"save_Interger_Value_For_Formula_One"];
    }

    NSInteger B = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"save_Interger_Value_For_Formula_One"];
    B = A;

    NSLog(@" B is: %d",B);
    B = A;
    NSLog(@" A is: %d",A);
}
```

Any Idea or suggestions would be highly welcome.

Comment: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`, dupe hundreds of times.

Comment: -synchronize will not help you at all within a single process

Comment: So what should I do Sir? Can you please give me some idea?

Comment: Can I use Plist here?

Comment: can  you please explain , what you want to do in your coding?

Comment: I want to save value without using plist and sqlite and retrive the value. The save value I can use in another class also. Can I do this from NSUserDefault?

Comment: Yes you can do this using NSUserDefault this is Permanant Storage....

Comment: NSInteger B; Declare Common in .h file and aceess here.. why you declare twice.

Comment: First you assign B = [[NSUserDefaults etc, and next line does B = A, which undoes everything you tried to prove

Comment: In your code initially you are setting 0 to A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to implement like this..Sure it'll help...

```
@implementation ClassA

- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:100 forKey:@"save_Interger_Value_For_Formula_One"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

@end

@implementation ClassB

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       int B = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]        integerForKey:@"save_Interger_Value_For_Formula_One"] integerValue];

     NSLog(@"Interger Value %d",b);
}
```

Comment: @NishaSingh Try to see my edited answer...I think you are getting different value that was not save.Because you are not converting value in interger..

Comment: sir I am getting value only for within the class if I go back to another class and come again in this class then The forkey does not remember the value like Plist and sqlite.

Comment: Wats your problem jst before u said me i'm not getting value n ryt now you r saying i'm getting again forKeyValue.So i'm not getting u proper...

Comment: sir I am getting value only for within the class if I go back to another class and come again in this class then The forkey does not remember the value like Plist and sqlite. Please check my code you are able to understand what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

To save an integer;

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:number forKey:@"unique_name"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To retrieve it;

```
NSInteger x = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"unique_name"];
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just `synchronize` your `NSUserDefaults` after inserting value.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

You can follow this answer [How to delete a user default value in NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342348/how-to-delete-a-user-default-value-in-nsuserdefaults/10600549#10600549)

In your code initially you are setting 0 to A, try this

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
{
        A = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"save_Interger_Value_For_Formula_One"];   
      [self calling_Once];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSUserDefaults * def=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [def setInteger:yourvalue forKey:@"YourKey"];
    [def synchronize];
```

Try this code....

Comment: Code is Working properly. But when I leave this class and enter again this class the  forkey not able to remember value.

Comment: NSString * str=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"save_Interger_Value_For_Formula_One"];
 
 NSLog(@"%@",str);