# - (IBAction)oneButton1:(id)sender

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to iOS, i want to update the text in ViewDidLoad() function.

This is my button function, When button is clicked animation take place and also adds the value "1" to "resultText.text"

```
   - (IBAction)oneButton1:(id)sender {
    oneBtn2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    CGRect frame = oneBtn1.frame;
    CGRect frame1 = reffButton.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame1.origin.x; 
    frame.origin.y = frame1.origin.y; 

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 3.0];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
        [oneBtn1 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.4, .4)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        oneBtn1.hidden = YES;
        price = [resultText.text intValue];

        [resultText setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", price+1]];

      }];
    oneBtn1.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

Problem: The above text value is 1 but in ViewDidLoad is 0 ,

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];

 NSLog(@"%@", resultText.text); // output is 0 instead of 1;

}
```

Please anyone tell me how to update the text value in ViewDidLoad function ...

Comment: if you want initial value as 1 then you can initialize it to 1. because viewDidLoad is first function to get called, it takes the default initialization value.

Comment: Yes, i try to initialize "price=0", is not working. i have 20 button function and text values (oneButton1, oneButton2, oneButton3, ...). The output text is (1, 2, 3, ...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ViewDidLoad calling only once when the object is creating .So you can't update the thing in ViewDidLoad.ViewDidLoad use for initialising the parameters and set the initial settings when an object creating.

Comment: Actually it can be loaded several times. viewDidLoad is called when view is loaded, but you can delete the view and load it again.

Comment: I have 20 buttons and each buttons has set value as "1"(resultText.text = 1), if the resultText.text =5 i want to display  animated gif  or image.  where i put this condition?

Answer (score 1):

This is because every time your view will load it create new object of your textField, thats  why you are unable to fetch previous (because its new textField not old one).So you have to save your text some where, for example you can use [NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342348/how-to-delete-a-user-default-value-in-nsuserdefaults/10600549#10600549)

**SetText**

```
NSString *result=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", price+1];

[resultText setText:];

//Also set it to NSUserDefaluts
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:result forKey:@"key"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**Get Text**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [resultText setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"key"]];
    NSLog(@"%@", resultText.text); 
}
```

**EDIT**

You can make animation afterButton click, so call this method in button click event

```
-(void)animateImage
{
    if ([resultText.text isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
        //make your animation
    }
}
```

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:nil forKey:@"key"];

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    price=0; [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:nil forKey:@"key"];
          
    [resultText setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"key"]];
    NSLog(@"%@", resultText.text); if([resultText.text isEqual: @"4"]) {
    
    [self performSelector:@selector(clownDanceAnimation) withObject:nil];
    } }    is this correct

Comment: It stores last entry values. How to clear that value .. why you want to clear the value?

Comment: tell me exact requirement

Comment: I have 20 buttons and each button click text value will store as "1"(resultText.text = 1) from that if the resultText.text =5 i want to display animated gif or image. and if the resultText.text=3 then i want to display another gif image.... This is my requirements

Comment: where are you putting this text resultText.text=3?

Comment: When button is clicked, i set the text as 1  i.e., [resultText setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", price+1]] ... second button is clicked, i set the text as 2 and so on. From that text result i will show animated gif when resultText = 3 and 5 ...

Comment: then whats the use of viewDidLoad in your project, like what you want to do with this?

Comment: to display the images or animated gif images using ViewDidLoad, because above condition is not working on button function. When i use this condition inside button function, the images will display whenever button is clicked.  I want output like this, When the resultText is 3 automatically image will appear.

Comment: call this function in button click method

Comment: -(void)animateImages{
    if ([resultText.text isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
        //do animation
    }
}

Comment: hey i have any question?

Comment: When button is clicked, image will display and same button or wherever in the view controller tap then image will disappear? what to do

Comment: sorry i typed wrongly,  Actually i asked to you... i want that solution to my project ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method  to do that

```
     - (void)updateLabel {
        oneBtn2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        CGRect frame = oneBtn1.frame;
        CGRect frame1 = reffButton.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame1.origin.x; 
        frame.origin.y = frame1.origin.y; 

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: 3.0];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
            [oneBtn1 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.4, .4)];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            oneBtn1.hidden = YES;
            price = [resultText.text intValue];

            [resultText setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", price+1]];

          }];
        oneBtn1.frame = frame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

   }


     - (void)viewDidLoad
     {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     [self updateLabel];
     NSLog(@"%@", resultText.text); // output is 0 instead of 1;

    }
```