# How to re-use a default value inside alamofire to another class / viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How to re-use a default value inside alamofire to another class / viewcontroller?

First I declare the saving value here
`let PointHistory = UserDefaults.standard`

then use it here

```
@IBAction func buttonPointHistory(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let parameters: Parameters=[
        "Card_No":labelCardNo.text!
    ]

    Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
        {
            response in

            print(response)

            self.PointHistory.set(PointHistoryURL, forKey: "Points")

    }
}
```

Now, my problem is how to return or re-use the stored values to other class or controller? I tried to re-use it like the normal declaration to another class but I did not get the value. What i am thinking is, its inside alamofire and did not return the value?

Answer (score 1):

**Store Value into User Defaults**

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
userDefaults.set(points, forKey: "Points")
```

**Retrieve the value**

```
if let points = userDefaults.integer(forKey: "Points") {
    // do something 
}
```

Acceptable Types:

- NSData
- String
- NSNumber

  - UInt
  - Int
  - Float
  - Double
  - Bool
- NSDate
- Array
- Dictionary

If you Need to Remove: [How to delete a user default value in NSUserDefaults?](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/41036402/4061501)

Comment: Hi! thanks for the response. I'am actually using this method, and that's is the problem, I cant retrieve the value to other class (NSObject)

Comment: can you show me your retrieving code? And what's its result? Is it Null?

Answer (score -1):

You have to add below line after adding any value in user default.

```
self.PointHistory.synchronize()
```

If you want to get that saved value then use below code.

```
let Str=UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:”yourkeyname”)
```

Example 
Save value in user defaults

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(“Jignesh”, forKey:”Myname”)
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Get value from user defaults

```
let Str=UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:”Myname”)
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the response. I'am actually using this method, and that's is the problem, I cant retrieve the value to other class (NSObject)

Comment: You do NOT need `.synchronize()`. This is obsolete now. It has been for a long time. There's warnings everywhere telling people to stop using it. Even the documentation explains it's useless. For apps with big defaults it can even cause lags and issues.