# Can I only remove one of UserDefaults item in Swift?

Tags: swift

I use UserDefault to save a Dictionary

Here's result when I print out my UserDefault

```
Optional({
Hamburger =     {
    count = 1;
    subtotal = 70;
};

Cake =     {
    count = 1;
    subtotal = 80;
};

Steak =     {
    count = 1;
    subtotal = 90;
  };

})
```

My question is Can I only remove one of key like Hamburger ?

Remain the rest of other two items

Just don't delete all UserDefault ,

only remove designated item

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342348/how-to-delete-a-user-default-value-in-nsuserdefaults

Comment: @RakeshaShastri this is not what I mean, I need to remove user defaults's item, not remove all user defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get get your dictionary from UserDefaults then you can remove the key/object you want. And then you can stored update object into UserDefault again.

```
       let kUserDefault = UserDefaults.standard

       let object = kUserDefault.object(forKey: "StoredValue") as! NSDictionary
        let storedValue = NSMutableDictionary.init(dictionary:object)
        storedValue.removeObject(forKey: "Hamburger")
        print(storedValue)

        kUserDefault.set(storedValue, forKey: "StoredValue")
        kUserDefault.synchronize()

        let newObject : NSMutableDictionary = kUserDefault.object(forKey: "StoredValue") as! NSMutableDictionary
        print(newObject)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I really appreciate ~  Good answer

Answer (score 0):

Find this solution:

```
    // To remove required value from dictionary
    let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    if var storedDictionary = userDefault.object(forKey: "StoredDictionary") as? [String: Any] {
        storedDictionary.removeValue(forKey: "Hamburger")
        userDefault.setValue(storedDictionary, forKey: "StoredDictionary")
    }

    // To fetch updated value again wherer you want.
    if let storedDictionary = userDefault.object(forKey: "StoredDictionary") as? [String: Any] {
        print("StoredDictionary: ", storedDictionary)
    }
```